# How to search words in close proximity to each other in Snowflake?

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose my table has a string column, i.e. `VARCHAR()`, each string is a sentence. I want to search for sentences in this column that have a certain word within close proximity near another word.

For example, if I want to search for sentences that have 'John' within two terms of 'Smith', in SQL Server, I do

```
SELECT row_id
FROM my_table
WHERE CONTAINS(sentence_column, 'NEAR((John, Smith), 2)')
```

How does this translate to Snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a UDF to approximate that syntax. This isn't intended to reproduce the *near* syntax of SQL server, but shows how it could be done. It only deals with spaces for word breaks, but could be modified to support other word breaks. It's case insensitive. If you want it to be case sensitive, you can remove the toUpperCase() methods.

```
create or replace function NEAR(STR string, STR1 string, STR2 string, DISTANCE float)
returns boolean
language javascript
as
$$
    var firstWord = -1;
    var secondWord = -1;
    var words = STR.split(" ");
    for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++){
        if (words[i].toUpperCase() === STR1.toUpperCase()) firstWord = i;
        if (words[i].toUpperCase() === STR2.toUpperCase()) secondWord = i;
    }
    return (firstWord >= 0) && (secondWord >= 0) && (secondWord - firstWord <= DISTANCE)
$$;

select near('John Jacob Smith', 'John', 'Smith', 2);  --True
select near('John Jacob Williams Smith', 'John', 'Smith', 2);  --False
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks! I modified it a bit to allow search a word contains another word within close proximity : line 11 ``` if (words[i].toUpperCase().includes(STR2.toUpperCase())) secondWord = i;```

Comment: @juju88 could you mark this question as the solution, it should be a button to the left of this answer, when you have a chance. Thank you!